# Convert DB2 SQL time (str) to time (HH:MM)

Tags: sql, time, db2

I´ve got the following table (column) in DB2:

```
TIME
04:30
05:00
...
```

This time **is storaged as character** Why someone did this is not clear to me. I would like to know how to convert this time into 'HH:MM' or 'HHMM' **time format** with DB2 SQL. The goal is to work with min(time) and max(time) afterwards. I haven´t been able to find an example here. Any hints?

Thank you!

(I hope the description is clearer now)

Comment: this is already in format 'HH:MM'?! So i do not understand what you are asking

Comment: You want to convert the character string `'nn:nn'` to `'nnnn'`? Use substring and concat.

Comment: Even better, use proper data types!

Comment: Yes, it´s storaged as **string format**. If I like to know e.g. the max(date) or min(date) then I have to convert this to date. Unfortunately, I don´t create this column so I need to find a solution.

Comment: You could Try TIME(). See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html. But it's a strange question. If TIME is a string with the time  HH:MM format, won't MIN(TIME) and MAX(TIME) give you the same answer as you would get from MIN(TIME(TIME)) and MAX(TIME(TIME))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following SQL statement if you have not tried it already:
'SELECT CONVERT(TIME, '06:30');'

Comment: I have already tried it  but it didn´t work. How would you do this if you want to convert the whole time column?

Comment: 'SELECT CONVERT(TIME,table_name.time) AS TIME FROM table_name'  
Or if you have to find the max or min of the time column then :
'SELECT MAX(CONVERT(TIME,table_name.time)) AS MAX_TIME FROM table_name

Comment: Huhm, it didn´t work for me. 
But I´ve just solved this using **CAST** function: To make sure that no special characters (in my case **..:..**) are stored in this table I exclude this using `case when table_name.time_1 != '..:..' then cast(table_name.time_1 as TIME )`. Due to the time field was storaged as varchar(9) I´ve used `select left(table_name.time, 5) as TIME` before to get only the first 5 characters. 
Thank you for support & input